# Using IIS to test php code without a domain name

Tags: php, iis

I am starting to work on a website for which I have not chosen a name or bought a domain. I enabled iis and installed php on my computer.

I want to create a temporary website just for testing my code, so I tried to add a website in the IIS Manager by right-clicking in the connections module and selecting "Add Website."

In this case I used "mywebsite.com" as a temporary name. The problem is that someone owns that domain and my browser takes me to their website instead of showing the local one. I tried changing the port from the default of 80 to 25, but I just then my browser says "page not found" when I try to view the webpage(right-click on site in IIS manager > Manage Website > Browse).

At this stage I just want to be able to see the output on my computer. Does anyone know I would do this?

Comment: I would recommend using wamp instead of doing what your doing http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Anything wrong with the good old localhost? But if you do want to use a website name - for example mywebsite.com - you have to edit your hosts file and point it to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a custom record that only resolves on your computer you can take the following approach:

1. Open notepad as an administrator
2. Open the file %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
3. Add the line "127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com"
4. Ensure that your IIS site actually binds to mywebsite.com:80
5. Save the file and attempt to resolve the domain name in your browser

However, I highly recommend that you attempt to use a domain name that is not actually real. For instance dev.lauren.local, instead of mywebsite.com, that way you will reduce the likelihood of unexpected results :)

Comment: Thank you! It worked using a .local address. I was initially getting a permissions error, but was able to fix is by adding User(<computername>/Users) as user. (select website in IIS Manager,click edit permissions in actions module, select security and then add user to group of user names)